How to open Terminal.app on MacOS by custom url in Google Chrome
I would like to open terminal app to run some custom command on my Mac for example:
terminal://test
Which will open terminal with command "doSomeMagic test"
How to do this? Is this even possible?
I searched Google but nothing found.
Similar question is for Windows, I need solution for MacOS on Macbook

No it is not. It is for Windows users. I need solution for MacOS.

Right. Perhaps this would be a good starting point for MacOS. If this does not help, I suggest that you post this in [apple.se]. Make sure that you put custom URL protocol in the title of your question.

This can be done quite easily with shell2http

Install shell2http with homebrew.

% brew install shell2http


Create your test.sh file in a new directory:

% mkdir web-launcher && cd web-launcher
% echo '#!/bin/bash\n\necho "Hello, World!"' > test.sh


Launch the server:

% shell2http /test "open -a Terminal test.sh"
2024/07/31 03:40:38 register: /test (open -a Terminal test.sh)
2024/07/31 03:40:38 register: / (index page)
2024/07/31 03:40:38 listen http://localhost:8080/


Launch the URL in your browser: http://localhost:8080/test

Terminal will open and run test.sh:


 %             
/path/to/web-launcher/test.sh ; exit;
Hello, World!

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.

[Process completed]

